# Why is my alert showing more than once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jQuery code:

```js
$("div.note a").live("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('test');
});
```

```html
<div id="note_list">

<div class="note">
Text 1
<a href="">X</a>
</div>

<div class="note">
Text 2
<a href="">X</a>
</div>

<div class="note">
Text 3
<a href="">X</a>
</div>

</div>
```

Could someone tell me why the alert shows 3 times? It works fine in Chrome but not in Firefox.

Comment: It appears only once for me: http://jsfiddle.net/s2ZAz/ `->` If there is a problem it is somewhere else in your code. Maybe you are adding the elements dynamically and binding the event handler every time? Then you did not understand what `live` is doing: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: might be you are assigning live event multiple times.try to unbind click event before assigning.

Comment: @sathis, yes I use live because the cose is loaded doing .html(html_code). Why .live() is not good? I mean...what do i have to unbind the event and then use live again?

Comment: @Dail: No, `live` is good when it is used correctly. But as it stands, we cannot reproduce your problem which either means you don't have a problem or you provide more code which might be related to the problem or you have to solve it by yourself.

Comment: @dail i suspect you are assigning a function to click event inside another event i.e every time you are assigning  a function to click event without clearing the previous one.

Comment: what assigning? i'm using the code i wrote above. how to clear?

Comment: @Dail: If this is the only code you are using, then it should work perfectly as you see by following the fiddle in my first comment. It seems to not work for you, that means there is something else you did not tell us about. How do you expect us to be able to help you if we don't know about it?

Comment: @Dail: Just a note to the answer you accepted: This just deals with the symptoms of your problem, it does not solve the cause (which is that you are someone binding an event handler several times). But it does not seem you want to provide further information about your code, so we cannot help you more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called onetime, in your case you can stop multiple event call by `e.stopImmediatePropagation();`

```
 $("div.note a").live("click", function(e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('test');
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("div.note a").die('click').live("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
   alert('test');
});
```

Comment: You cannot unbind event handlers bound with `live` this way (if that's your intention). You have to use `die`.

Comment: @sathis, could you explain wky do i have to unbind and then bind again ?

Comment: @FelixKling, die instead of live? why?

Comment: @Dail: I never said `die` instead of `live`. I said if one wants to *unbind* an event handler bound with `live`, `die` has to be used instead of `unbind`. For why, please have a look at the documentation.