# Javascript: alert showing more than once

Tags: javascript, html

There are other threads about this, but dont apply to my context.

Like: [Alert returning more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27610879/alert-returning-more-than-once)

[Why is my alert showing more than once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822407/why-is-my-alert-showing-more-than-once)

I'm learning about JS.

**OBJECTIVE**:

1.- On load page ask your name.

2.- On clicking button it should return: "Hello [name]. Today is [date/year]".

It does the job correctly, but when i click the button:

a) First time: i see just one alert.
b) Second time: i see two alerts.
c) Thrid time: i see three alerts.
d) And so on.

I've waited the page to load, etc. I don't know why this behaviour (Same on Chrome and Firefox, latest versions).

**My code:**

**JS:**

```
document.addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
    btn1 = document.getElementById("mybtn")
    btn1.addEventListener("click", function () {alert(messageParts.join(""));}, false);

}


function getMonthName(index) {
  var months = ["January", "February", "March",
    "April", "May", "June", "July", "August",
    "September", "October", "November", "December"
  ];
  return months[index];
}


function abbrName(text) {
  return text.substr(0, 3);
}

var date = new Date();

var messageParts = [
  "Hello, ",
  prompt("Please, enter your name", "Please, enter your name"),
  ". Today is ",
  date.getDate(),
  " ",
  abbrName(getMonthName(date.getMonth())),
  " ",
  ", ",
  date.getFullYear()
];
```

**HTML**

```
<!doctype HTML>

<html lang="es">
    <div id="headerr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="website.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="stack.js"></script>
    </head>
    </div>
    <body>

        <article>
          <h1>Función User's name and date</h1>
          <p>Nombre y fecha del día</p>
          <section>
            <button id="mybtn">Click to enter your name !</button>
          </section>
        </article>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this what you want to do? http://jsfiddle.net/r63u9g60/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are binding a function to the `click` event on the `document`, and in that function you are binding another handler to the `click` event of your button.

Which means every time you click on the document (this includes any children of the document object, like your button), you are adding a new listener, and all the listeners bound to an event on that object will fire when that event is triggered.

So when you click on the page the first time, the button has one listener added to it, and when you click the button to trigger your alert, you're adding a second listener. The second time you click, it will fire both of those handler functions, and also bind a third one, and so on.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/L707ak04/2/) is a demonstration that shows you how many listeners you have bound to your button. It goes up any time you click anywhere on the page, including on the button, so you can see exactly how many times you will see the `alert`.

Also note that having the function calls in the array (like `prompt()`) will execute them as soon as the array is created. In your code, that array is created as soon as the page loads. What you want to be doing is creating that array *inside* the handler for the button, so the user is asked to input their name only after clicking the button:

```
var btn1 = document.getElementById("mybtn")
btn1.addEventListener("click", function () {
    var date = new Date();
    var messageParts = [
        "Hello, ",
        prompt("Please, enter your name", "Please, enter your name"),
        ". Today is ",
        date.getDate(),
        " ",
        abbrName(getMonthName(date.getMonth())),
        " ",
        ", ",
        date.getFullYear()
    ];

    alert(messageParts.join(""));
}, false);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/L707ak04/3/).

Comment: @Thanks for the great explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You are adding a new Event listener which will call the action each time you click on your button.

**EDIT:**

Here is the jsfiddle of your code:
http://jsfiddle.net/L707ak04/

Here is a simple new version: http://jsfiddle.net/L707ak04/1/

Simply doing:

```
btn1 = document.getElementById("mybtn")
btn1.addEventListener("click", function () {alert(messageParts.join(""));}, false);
```

without calling this in an event listener.